# Unification of the 2 methods

Tags: c#

I need some help. I need to combine these two methods into one and I can't figure out how.

I tried with an IF statement (we checked if employeeMark is NullOrEmpty, we use the first logic and if it's not, the second logic) but it's just duplicated code in one method instead of two.

This is the first method :

```
private async Task<ProcessedContractsIdentifiers> GetContractsIdentifiersByContractsCodes(List<ImportableContractIdentifier> importableContractsIdentifiers)
        {
            var errors = new List<ContractImportValidationErrorDto>();

            foreach (var contract in importableContractsIdentifiers.Where(contract => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contract.ContractCode)))
            {
                errors.Add(new ContractImportValidationErrorDto
                {
                    ValidatedCode = string.Empty,
                    Line = contract.RowNumber,
                    ErrorCode = ContractImportValidationErrorCode.ContractCodeIsRequired
                });
            }
            var contractsCodes = importableContractsIdentifiers.ConvertAll(x => x.ContractCode);
            contractsCodes = contractsCodes.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();

            var contractsSignatures = await GetContractsSignaturesByContractsCodes(contractsCodes);
            var unresolvedContracts = contractsCodes.Except(contractsSignatures.Select(cs => cs.Code)).ToHashSet();
            foreach (var c in unresolvedContracts)
            {
                errors.Add(new ContractImportValidationErrorDto
                {
                    ValidatedCode = c,
                    ErrorCode = ContractImportValidationErrorCode.InvalidContractCode
                });
            }

            return new ProcessedContractsIdentifiers
            {
                IdentificationMethod = ContractIdentificationMethod.ByContractCode,
                IdentifiedContractsSignatures = contractsSignatures,
                NonIdentifiableContracts = errors
            };
        }
```

And this is the second method :

```
private async Task<ProcessedContractsIdentifiers> GetContractsIdentifiersByEmployeesMarks(List<ImportableContractIdentifier> importableContractsIdentifiers)
        {
            const int withSingleContract = 1;
            var errors = new List<ContractImportValidationErrorDto>();

            foreach (var contract in importableContractsIdentifiers.Where(contract => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contract.EmployeeMark)))
            {
                errors.Add(new ContractImportValidationErrorDto
                {
                    ValidatedCode = string.Empty,
                    Line = contract.RowNumber,
                    ErrorCode = ContractImportValidationErrorCode.EmployeeMarkIsRequired
                });
            }
            var employeesMarks = importableContractsIdentifiers.Select(x => x.EmployeeMark).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToHashSet();

            var contractsSignatures = await GetContractsSignaturesByEmployeeMark(employeesMarks);
            var contractsGroupedByEmployeeMark = contractsSignatures.GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeMark);

            foreach (var contracts in contractsGroupedByEmployeeMark.Where(x => x.ToList().Count != withSingleContract))
            {
                errors.Add(new ContractImportValidationErrorDto
                {
                    ValidatedCode = contracts.Key,
                    ErrorCode = ContractImportValidationErrorCode.EmployeeMarkWithMultipleContracts
                });
            }

            var unresolvedMarks = employeesMarks.Except(contractsSignatures.Select(cs => cs.EmployeeMark)).ToHashSet();
            foreach (var eMark in unresolvedMarks)
            {
                errors.Add(new ContractImportValidationErrorDto
                {
                    ValidatedCode = eMark,
                    ErrorCode = ContractImportValidationErrorCode.InvalidEmployeeMark
                });
            }

            return new ProcessedContractsIdentifiers
            {
                IdentificationMethod = ContractIdentificationMethod.ByEmployeeMark,
                IdentifiedContractsSignatures = contractsSignatures,
                NonIdentifiableContracts = errors
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Enum  as parameter, so according to its value you can write code blocks.

```
public Enum IOMode
{
    In=0,
    Out=1
}
public void CalculateAttendance(List<Log> lstLog, IOMode eIOMode) 
{
   if(eIOMode==IOMode.In)
   {}
   else
   { } 
}

call CalculateAttendance(lstLog, IOMode.In) etc
```